# Подставить данные в строку в разных местах из массива

Tags: golang

Есть строка

```
Статистика с %s по %s
```

Как ввести данные из массива в эти 2 места, если есть всего 2 элемента массива с помощью fmt.printf():

```
params := ["20 февраля 2021", "21 февраля 2021"]

fmt.Printf("Статистика с %s по %s", params...)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fmt.Printf` принимает слайс интерфейсов. надо массив строк привести к этому типу.

```
func main() {
    params := []string{"20 февраля 2021", "21 февраля 2021"}
    fmt.Printf("Статистика с %s по %s", intfceSlice(params)...)
}


func intfceSlice(s []string) []interface{} {
    res := make([]interface{}, 0, len(s))
    for _, i := range s {
        res = append(res, i)
    }
    return res
}
```

Ответ

> Статистика с 20 февраля 2021 по 21 февраля 2021

Answer (score 2):

Если вы уверены в том, что params содержит минимум два элемента, то достаточно подставить эти элементы:

```
params := []string{"20 февраля 2021", "21 февраля 2021"}
fmt.Printf("Статистика с %s по %s", params[0], params[1])
```